# spring data dynamodb with no mapper annotations

Tags: spring-data, amazon-dynamodb

I have a group of generated domain entities that i would like to extend for use with spring-data-dynamodb. I'm trying to figure out a way to do that without altering the base classes. Any help would be much appreciated.

I'd like to do something like:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "ReferenceData")
public class ReferenceDataDynamo extends ReferenceData {

  private String id;

  @DynamoDBHashKey
  @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

}
```

But as far as i can tell the mapper can't map the fields from the base class without at least a @DynamoDBDocument annotation.

```
 no mapping for attribute by name
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperTableModel.field(DynamoDBMapperTableModel.java:94) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.336.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in the current version of the aws dynamo sdk. See https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/35 for more details.